# Mobile web-design: alternative to "title" atribute in HTML tags

Tags: html, mobile-browser

Is there an alternative for the title="" attribute in HTML tags that works in mobile browsers?

Comment: What effect do you want to have? Hover does not have the same importance in mobile than it has in desktop.

Comment: The tooltip effect, for example I have a small column with a bunch of text, this is annoying to read. At a desktop browser you can simply add the title attribute which shows the long text read-able in a tooltip. But this isn't possible in mobile browsers.

Comment: So as you say yourself a direct equivalent is not available in mobile environments. So what you actually seek is a substitute for tooltips, which as a question is maybe a better fit to http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's **no** alternative because the `title` attribute triggers a **tooltip** `on hover` but you can't *hover* in mobile browsers (for smartphones). An alternative action to *hover* in mobile browsers can be `hold`. So you can use **jquery** to do something like:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="x" title="Hello World">Hold this element</div>
```

**jquery:**

```
$('#x').tooltip({trigger: 'manual'});
$('#x').on("taphold",function(){
    $(this).tooltip('show');
});
```

**NOTE**: **jquery**, **jquery mobile** and **bootstrap** (js and css) are **required** for this example.
You can use any other css library or make the tooltip yourself if you want, but you get the idea...

Answer (score 3):

A CSS only alternative is to use the `:active` state and `:after` or `:before` pseudo element and use the title attribute for the content, example:

```
.element:active:after{
  content:attr(title);
}
```

you may want to style it so simulate a tooltip!

Comment: I would use `:hover` instead of `:active`.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the issue by using the following code.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.likeIcon').tooltip({trigger: 'manual'});
    $('.likeIcon').on("taphold",function(){
        $(this).tooltip('show');
    });
});
```